# Shapefile to csv with a WKT multipolygon column

Tags: csv, shapefile, gdal

My data is from [census maps](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html). I am not familiar with shapefiles or WKT file, but I managed to find this [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/how-to-convert-shp-to-csv-including-attributes-and-geometry), on by which I tried to create my own code.

```
import ogr
import csv

#Open files
csvfile=open("states_wkt.csv",'wb')
ds=ogr.Open("cb_2015_us_state_20m.shp")
lyr=ds.GetLayer()

#Get field names
dfn=lyr.GetLayerDefn()
nfields=dfn.GetFieldCount()
fields=[]
for i in range(nfields):
    fields.append(dfn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
fields.append('kmlgeometry')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fields)
```

While this works, i get geometry results looking like:

```
""kmlgeometry"":""<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-118.593969,33.467198
-118.484785,33.487483 -118.370323,33.409285 -118.286261
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
 <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-118.594033,33.035951
-118.540069,32.980933 -118.446771,32.895424 -118.353504,32.821962 -118.425634
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

In my specific case I would like to return geometry data in a form of multipolygon like this:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.6062550000000044 42.0133709999999994, 
-71.5276060000000058 42.0149979999999985, -71.5169060000000059 
42.0155979999999971, -71.4999080000000049 42.0171989999999980, 
-71.3814009999999968 42.0187979999999968, -71.3815050000000042 
42.0000110000000006, -71.3812010000000043 41.9811979999999991)))
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the result at all, at what point do you extract the KML? Either way, ogr features/geoms have an `ExportToJSON` method as well.

Comment: Well this code did produce this result. I just shortened it for readibility. Anyway thanks for the hint that this was KML format. What I ended up doing is `ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv myshape.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT` which I found in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/converting-shapefiles-to-text-ascii-files

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a simple script that is easy to use using GDAL:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV multipolygon_states.csv cb_2015_us_state_20m.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT
```